# Laravel show 404 page If Missing required parameters Error

Tags: laravel

I have a language switcher in the web routes. when I type http://example.com/asds wrong url it redirects me to the Error page with `Missing required parameters for [Route: home] [URI: {language}/home].` How to redirect to 404 page if wrong url ?

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'{language}','where' => ['language' => '[a-zA-z]{2}']],function () {
Route::get('/contact', function () {
})->name('contact');

class UrlGenerationException extends Exception
{
    /**
     * Create a new exception for missing route parameters.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Route  $route
     * @return static
     */
    public static function forMissingParameters($route)
    {
        return new static("Missing required parameters for [Route: {$route->getName()}] [URI: {$route->uri()}].");
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you have `APP_DEBUG` set to `true`? If you set `APP_DEBUG` to `false` it should redirect you to the 404 page.

Comment: No it is still showing the  Error page

Comment: After APP_DEBUG to false it is showing 500 error page